# Has Hillary Clinton been a Cubs and a Yankees fan for years?

Tags: sport, hillary-clinton

[image]

According to this image circling the Internet, Clinton is on record this week saying that she is a life long Cubs fan. Yet her previous statements claim she's been a Yankee fan for years.

Did she claim to be fan of both teams?

Comment: Is the implication supposed to be that only one can be true?

Comment: @IsBegot i think both Can be true, im more interested personally to know if her cubs statement is simply bandwagoning, or if she has prior claims of support.

Comment: Ok, but "fan" is a very fuzzy concept. What objective standard would we use to determine whether or not she was a fan of any given sports team at any given moment in time?

Comment: @NateEldredge the questions simple. being a fan is based on the honor system, she says shes always been a fan, were looking to see if she has previously stated this in the past to self confirm, or a statement in the past self deny.

Comment: Let's avoid pointless arguments. I've re-edited the question so it's not about the exact quotes, but her self-reported affiliation.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Yes, Clinton has self-admittedly been a fan of both clubs for years.

We can see from her opponents' view on the issues (obviously painted with a negative slant) that Hillary Clinton has claimed to be a long-time fan of both the Cubs and Yankees.

[GOP.com](https://gop.com/bandwagon-hillary/)  (the website of the Republican Party, Clinton's opponent in the elections) claims that (emphasis mine):

> In the early 1990s, **Clinton pledged allegiance to the Cubs**, claiming she’d been a lifelong fan in an interview with Esquire. But running for the Senate in New York, Clinton claimed she’d “always been a Yankees fan.”
>
> In 2006 **Clinton Said The Cubs And Yankees Were Her Favorite Teams** “Growing Up And Now In My More Mature Years.”
>
> CLINTON: “Thank you very, very much, Jonathan. I don't have time to rebut everything you've said in your introduction. But I cannot let stand that I have ever, ever been a Mets fan. Have to set the record straight. **Cubs and Yankees: Those were my teams, and remain my teams, growing up and now in my more mature years**.” (Hillary Clinton, Remarks, Washington, DC, 5/23/06)
>
> While Running For Senate, Clinton Said That “She'd ‘Always Been A Yankees Fan.’”
>
> “Later, Clinton asserted that she'd 'always been a Yankees fan.' Couric correctly challenged her, saying she thought the first lady, a native of Illinois, was a Chicago Cubs fan. 'I am a Cubs fan,' Clinton said. '**But I needed an American League team … so as a young girl, I became very interested and enamored of the Yankees**.’”

Clinton has claimed consistently to be a fan of the Yankees since 1999, therefore she is qualified to claim that she has been a Yankees fan for years (although her support before 1999 is doubtful).

She has also consistently claimed that she had always been a Cubs fan while growing up, and that she chose to support the Yankees as well because the Cubs were not winning enough.

Comment: perfect exactly what i was looking for, ill let it chill for a day or so but most likely accepted